# Highcharts: getting duplicate items in export menu when adding custom export options

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, export, data-visualization

I have a web page where I'm displaying two Highcharts visualizations. I'm adding a new export option to each of these two charts so users can download an Excel spreadsheet that's relevant to each chart's data. I already have an array of export options in `Highcharts.setOptions()` for use with event tracking; these options are used with other charts on my website and is meant to be universal.

**Here's my challenge:** the code to add the new export option works, but it adds it to **both** charts, not just the one I want. I'm not sure why this is happening, as I'm explicitly adding the new option to only the relevant chart's array of options.

A working fiddle of my code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/brightmatrix/qr422sjk/2/.

The key piece of code where I'm adding the new export options is as follows:

```
var drawChart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(chart1);
drawChart1.options.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
    text: 'Download Excel spreadsheet (chart #1)',
    onclick: function () {
        window.open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bDffOyfCe0gWLqmXwW5TrlQ8RkfFDXiMqyNhRXlNlDU/edit#gid=0');
    }
});

var drawChart2 = new Highcharts.Chart(chart2);
drawChart2.options.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
    text: 'Download Excel spreadsheet (chart #2)',
    onclick: function () {
        window.open('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bDffOyfCe0gWLqmXwW5TrlQ8RkfFDXiMqyNhRXlNlDU/edit#gid=0');
    }
});
```

Here's what I see when I toggle the Export menu in either chart:

[image]

Any advice or guidance would be most welcome. Thank you!

Comment: The reason of that is apply exporintg buttons by setOptions. Declare that only in particular chart, then you avoid two items in each chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sebastian already wrote in a comment - if you will use `Highcharts.setOptions()` before creating each chart, then both chart's will have only set options.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qr422sjk/3/

Comment: Ah, I see now! Thank you (and @SebastianBochen) very much for reviewing my question and solving this issue.